# Project Reactor/Webflux: limit subscription time and pass another object downstream

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I have a method that accepts "infinite" subscriptions:

```
 @GetMapping("/sse")
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent<UserUpdateResponse>> handleSse(String id) {
        return usersSink.asFlux()
                .filter(update -> id.equals(update.getId()))
                .map(this::wrapIntoSse);
    }
```

I want to limit the time of the subscription and when the timer expires produce an object that will be passed to the downstream.

Basically, I want `takeUntilOther()` with a way to change the object. Instead of waiting until the filter matches, I want to create an object myself and pass it to the consumers of the above Flux.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to cancel subscription but I don't think such operator exists. Also, as far as I know WebFlux doesn't provide any mechanism to access active subscriptions. For example, in Netty subscription happens in [HttpServer](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/db27625064fc78f8374c1ef0af3160ec3ae979f4/reactor-netty-http/src/main/java/reactor/netty/http/server/HttpServer.java#L962).

Not sure about side-effects but you could get access to subscription using `doOnSubscribe` and keep it in some cache that allow to set TTL for entries. Then in removal listener we could cancel subscription.

Here is an example with Caffeine cache but you could use some custom implementation and have background thread monitoring entries and evict expired values.

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class StreamingController {
    private final Cache<String, Subscription> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterWrite(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .removalListener((String key, Subscription subscription, RemovalCause cause) -> {
                log.info("Canceling subscription: {}", key);
                subscription.cancel();
            })
            .build();

    @GetMapping("/sse")
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent<UserUpdateResponse>> handleSse(String id) {
        return usersSink.asFlux()
                .filter(update -> id.equals(update.getId()))
                .map(this::wrapIntoSse)
                .doOnSubscribe(s -> {
                    this.cache.put(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), s);
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: timeout in case of Flux measures the time between onNext events, it might not be suitable for this use case

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, @MartinTarjányi is right, that's not what I'm looking for. I'd like to have a timeout run from the moment of first subscription.

Comment: There is overload that allow you to handle the first signal from the `Flux` https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#timeout-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: This is still not what I'm looking for. The point of this method is to keep the client connected and send them notifications (SSE) from the sink/flux directly. I want to limit every client subscription time (whether they received any data or not) by 24h. When a client exceeds the given time, the server should send a notification that the time was exceeded and close the connection (basically the current stream should be closed).

Comment: there are some contradictive requirements. could you share more details regarding `usersSink` and how these events are generated to better understand the use case.

Comment: There is a service that sends events about changes in users' info over AMQP to the service with `usersSink` (`Sinks.unsafe().many().multicast().directBestEffort()`). Events then are emitted trough `usersSink`.
From the other side, third party services want to know about users' updates. They subscribe to the updates for a user by opening a persistent HTTP connection to `/sse` (with the given user id).
I want is to limit the time a client can keep the HTTP connection open. With my current knowledge of WebFlux, I need to somehow cancel subscription.

Comment: @JohnnyBGoode
 "I want is to limit the time a client can keep the HTTP connection". Is it only in case there is no data received?

Comment: @Alex, no. Whether data received or not, the connection must be closed after 24 hours with a final message saying why it's closed.

Comment: We need to cancel subscription. In Reactor everything is based on signals and  I don't think such operator exists. Updated the answer with some ideas.

Comment: @Alex, I really appreciate your help, thank you. But it seems you forgot that the main goal is not to just cancel subscription, but to send the clients the final event over the HTTP connection. I could cancel subscription with `takeUntilOther(Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(3)))`. The main problem is I don't know how to send the notification to the client that their connection is going to be closed due to timeout.